# How to write multiple css on ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I want multiple css changes need to be done while clicking button

for ex:  `ng-click="myStyle={'background-color':'black'}; myStyle={color:'blue'}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to do similar.

```
<span ng-click="elemStyle={'background-color': '#000', 'color': blue}" 
      ng-style="elemStyle">some text</span>
```

Comment: thanks this works. I need an another help. i want to pass the dynamic style values. how to get that from ng-model. for ex: <input type='text' ng-model='backgroundColor'> <span ng-click="elemStyle={'background-color': {{backgroundColor}}, 'color': blue}"

Comment: Imo better to create method in $scope for this case.

Answer (score 0):

It is more advisable (for your own sake) to assign different classes to the element depending on the needs rather than just plain CSS.

Please see AngularJS [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive for that functionality.

In this example element will toggle between having foo and bar class when clicked:

```
<div 
     data-ng-click="toggleClass = !toggleClass" 
     data-ng-class="{foo: toggleClass, bar: !toggleClass}">
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hpeinar/oLak27xx/